# Azure Virtual Network doubts

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, virtual-network

I would like to set up a Virtual Network in Microsoft Azure but I have a few doubts about it.

Can I link a Virtual Machine in another Azure account to my VN?
Is it possible to forward all traffic to a VM with an IDS (snort) and then to the actual VM serving the content?
Is it worth it (for security reasons) to use a VN over a simple VM connected to the internet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Virtual Networks do not span Azure subscriptions. You must have all of your VMs in the same subscription, for them to share a Virtual Network. You *can* bridge VNs across regions, and across deployments. Just not past the subscription edge (e.g. the billing boundary).

Only you can decide whether to use a VN vs direct-connect over the Internet. However, once you go over the Internet, you'll need to concern yourself with:

- Allowed/denied traffic (this can be handled with Azure's Access Control Lists)
- Secure data (e.g. https/ssl)
- Port access per VM (with classic VM deployment, you may only only open 150 ports per deployment)

Answer (score 0):

With the new v2 / Resource Manager machines it isn't possible to have a machine that isn't in a VNet.

You can set the routing table for a VNet to feed all traffic into a particular VM. That could be a snort box.

You could certainly set up the snort box to be a (set of) front end proxy and let it sniff the traffic as it directs and load balances it.

Whether it is worth it is a question for you though, whether you think your application is at enough risk to warrant the additional work / cost.

As for linking a machine from another account? Do you mean having machine from separate subscriptions in the same VNet? no you can't. What you can do though is create a VPN link between them and have them within a similar IP range.

Comment: Actually, I have two VMs, one running Laravel and another MySQL, that is why I wanted to have a VN. Connection to another subscription is because I  would like to move the MySQL to the other subscription so that I can scale up (150$/mo are not enough for three VMs on Azure). How can I setup the snort box? Can it be a very small VM (like a shared 500 MB), given that I have around 200 active users/day? thanks :)